# How do I silence Messages from a single person on my Apple Watch?

Tags: messages, apple-watch, watchos

I have a particular person who continually messages me but I do not want to block them. Is there anyway to silence my watch so I do not get notifications from them, but I still get them from others?

Comment: You can turn do-not-disturb on for a single person on your iPhone. This will also apply to the watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set a conversation in Messages to "Do Not Disturb". This will cause notifications to stop and will put a small moon icon next to the conversation. Works great!